# js Can plugin be written in this way? get elment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, element

I dont know whether this way will work please advice.

I am trying to make the plugin can be call in this way, `$(el).plugin.a()` not either `$(el).plugin()` or `$(el).plugin().a()`

I dont know how to do that, or whether if its possible. Thank you very much for your advice.

Below code I can read giving parement in a function, but cant read the element. Please help and advice a way to get the element.

```
$.fn.plugin = {
  a : function(aa){
    alert(aa);
    //HOW READ ELMENT HERE??  <- $(el)
    //the 'this' here mean the object variable plugin himself 
  },
}


$(el).plugin.a('xx');
```

Comment: what element are you trying to read? HTML elements?

Comment: $(el)  <- element, how can i call 'el' and apply $.each(el, function(){}); and etc inside of a?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use a simple alternative syntax;

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {

      var methods = {
           a : function() {
               .. do something ..
               Note: 'this' is a jQuery object, when executed.
           },
           b : function() {
               .. do something ..
               Note: 'this' is a jQuery object, when executed.
           }
      };

      $.extend(this, methods);

      return this;
};
```

See also this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8zwC/2/

Comment: No, that is not possible, as you will completely loose the reference to the original jQuery object. Syntax like $(el).plugin().a.b.c would theoretically be possible, but would require some hacking.